# Buffer Overflow using c

Tags: c, buffer, buffer-overflow

I'm attempting to create a buffer overflow which will overwrite the variable "b" with the value of "31337". The compiled file is called "bo" The buffer has a size of 010 which is 8 bytes, so I filled it with "AAAAAAAA" and 31337 is 7A69 in hexadecimal. Therefore, the following command in Linux should work in theory but it is unsuccessful:

```
printf 'AAAAAAAA\x69\x7A\x00\x00' | ./bo
```

The above command is supposed to overwrite the "b" variable. It works if I change the b variable to 1337 and the command to the following:

```
printf 'xxxxxxxx\x39\x05\x00\x00' | ./bo
```

1337 is 539 in hexadecimal.

Here are the command results from the terminal

```
root@kali:~# printf 'AAAAAAAA\x69\x7A\x00\x00' | ./bo
1111638594
```

I expected 31337

```
root@kali:~# printf 'AAAAAAAA\x39\x05\x00\x00' | ./bo
1337
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? It worked for the hexadecimal 1337, but not 31337. The following is the source code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int play()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char buffer[010];
    a = 0x41414141;
    b = 0x42424242;

    if (read(STDIN_FILENO, &buffer, 0xC) < 0) 
        perror("read");

    printf("%d\n", b);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    play();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: You are invoking undefined bahaviour. Therefore the outcome of your code can not be predicted in general.

Comment: I don't see where you are overwriting the buffer.

Comment: @klutt I'm sorry, what do you mean that the code "worked for you"? Were you able to get the buffer overflow to work? I'm unsure what undefined behavior is.

Comment: 'I'm attempting to create a buffer overflow'.. why?  How is that useful to future users/visitors?

Comment: It executed `readfile("Success.txt")`. Undefined behavior means that the behavior is undefined. It may do anything, including working as expected.

Comment: @klutt How did you get it to execute Success.txt, by simply compiling and running the code, or did you input data from the printf command I provided?  Please understand I'm not proficient with c, so I'm not sure where in the code the undefined behavior exists or how to fix it.

Comment: @Martin James It's for educational purposes only. It will help future users who have the same interest.

Comment: I used the piping you mentioned. When you access memory you do not have access to, you have undefined behavior. You seem to assume that `b` is positioned next to `buffer`. Why?

Comment: You have several possible problems here, which is why "hacking" is not easy. First, the C compiler isn't obligated to put your variables in any particular order, so your buffer overflow may not overwrite what you want. Second, if you build with optimizations on your if statement will disappear, because the compiler can see it can never be true, according to the rules of C.

Comment: Why don't you get a compilation error here: `readfile("Success.txt";`?

Comment: So you wonder why **undefined** behaviour behaves undefined?

Comment: @babon Sorry, I copied it in wrong. It had the closing bracket when I actually used it. Changed it.

Comment: @klutt Well, I'm basing it on the fact that I was able to reliably change the b variable to "1337" with piping the other printf command. I'm used to using immunity debugger or gdb and Kali's ruby scripts to find the EIP position and such, but it's not getting a segmentation fault so I haven't figured out a way to figure out the EIP yet in this case.

Comment: @klutt How did you compile it? I used gcc -o bo bo.c -fno-stack-protector -ggdb

Comment: @CodingNovice I just used cc without any flags.

Comment: @CodingNovice Besides. It was me who removed a lot of code from your post, since it was not necessary to understand the problem. Please read about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @klutt Ah I see, I thought something was going wrong in the site. I won't mess with it. Thanks again for your instruction. I'll research undefined behavior and try to gain a deeper understanding of c going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assume that the variables will have a certain location on the stack. However, there is a way to enforce it. You can do like this:

```
int play()
{
    struct {
        int a;
        char buffer[010];
        int b;
    } vars;

    vars.a = 0x41414141;
    vars.b = 0x42424242;

    if (read(STDIN_FILENO, &vars.buffer, 0xC) < 0) 
        perror("read");

    printf("%d\n", vars.b);
}
```

This will enforce the order of the variables in memory. When I tried this, it worked, but when I switched the order

```
struct {
    int a;
    int b;
    char buffer[010];
} vars;
```

it does not.

I'm not sure how much you can trust or use this though. This only guarantees that `&a<&buffer<&b`. It does not guarantee that `&(a+1)=&buffer`. In fact, if `a` is a variable of a one-byte type it will not be the case.

Here is an example of how order matters:

```
int main()
{
    struct {
        char x;
        int a;
        char y;
    } v;

    struct {
        char x;
        char y;
        int a;
    } w;

    printf("%d\n", sizeof(v));
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(w));
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
12
8
```

The fact that the size of a struct may change if you reorder the variables is a reason to that the compiler is not allowed to reorder them.

Comment: Awesome. I just confirmed that changing the ordering did work. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @CodingNovice Just remember that you are playing with fire when doing stuff like this. It's likely that you will cause undefined behavior. Search for this term and read about it, and you'll see that you want to avoid it if you can, because it makes things extremely hard to debug. (When you're not doing hackish stuff like this you want to avoid it at all costs.) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Comment: @klutt Since OP has specified that they are using gcc, you can add `__attribute__((packed))` on the struct definition to ensure no padding. Although it is just a hint to the compiler, it might help.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Since it is just a hint, it is a pretty bad idea to rely on it. :)

Comment: @klutt it is more than just making a struct (since it would most definitely have padding if a char is between integers). But I will leave it to your judgement.